# boot script is not called on boot

Tags: boot, init.d

I have the following script named `/etc/init.d/asplashscreen`:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          asplashscreen
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:      
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Show custom splashscreen
# Description:       Show custom splashscreen
### END INIT INFO


do_start () {
    echo "this script is called on boot" >> /cca-debug
    #/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash.png    
    exit 0
}

case "$1" in
  start|"")
    do_start
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
  stop)
    # No-op
    ;;
  status)
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

The file is installed correctly:

```
$ sudo find /etc -iname "*asplashscreen*"
/etc/init.d/asplashscreen
/etc/rcS.d/S01asplashscreen
```

I can not see `/cca-debug` file when rebooted.

Comment: Just keeping this file in `init.d` is not enough. You will need proper rights to execute and install it using these commands. `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/asplashscreen`
`sudo insserv /etc/init.d/asplashscreen`. If you already did it, may I know which kernel and os you're using ?  Add output of `uname -a`.

Comment: As per @dastaan, note that Raspbian Jessie uses systemd, not init, so if that is your OS you will need to register your script differently.

Comment: @PhilB. I think adding the script via `insserv` should still work as systemd uses an adapter taskr to run `rc.d` stuff for backward compatibility.  As per the manpage though, "It is not recommended to execute insserv directly  [...] update-rc.d is the recommended interface for managing init scripts".  Looks like ceremcem has done this already anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `/etc/rcS.d/S01asplashscreen`

This prioritizes this script to run ahead of pretty much everything else; on default Raspbian, the only things with `S01` in `rcS.d` are `fake-hwclock`, `hostname`, and `mountkernfs`.  Hence:

> `echo "this script is called on boot" >> /cca-debug`

Will likely fail, because the root filesystem has not been remounted read-write.  If you change the priority:

```
mv /etc/rcS.d/S01asplashscreen /etc/rcS.d/S20asplashscreen
```

You should get the message.  You could do this more properly by using `Required-Start: mountall.sh` ([see here](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)) and re-adding via `update-rc.d`, but of course, that's probably not what you want with a splash screen.  You want it to happen first.

However, just renaming the symlink temporarily should be enough to write the echo properly and prove whether or not the script is being run.

If so, you might try using `checkfs.sh` as the `Required-Start`.  I think trying to run a framebuffer app on the same tty as the console output could be a problem, though.

BTW, if you are doing all this yourself, you might as well learn systemd instead of SysV init since the latter is more or less defunct on linux as of Debian/Raspbian 8 (jessie).

Comment: I changed the `Required-Start: ` line as `Required-Start: checkfs.sh` and it worked as expected. I removed the `checkfs.sh` part, it worked anyway... Then I moved on and changed the `/boot/cmdline.txt` as `... console=tty3 quiet loglevel=3 ...` in order to remove the texts at the beginning of the boot process, then rebooted. Nothing showed up. No kernel messages, no boot messages, no splash screen. Then I changed `/boot/cmdline.txt` back to original, nothing changed. Then I added `Require... checkfs.sh`, it gave the error "checkfs.sh must be enabled...". Now I removed asplashscreen via insserv

Comment: changing `Required-Start: ` line as `Required-Start: checkfs` solved the problem. After that I installed script via `update-rc.d asplashscreen defaults`. Thank you.